# Can I pass custom value to the calculated column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to append custom value to the calculated column which is already created in Power BI.

I have created below switch statement by creating new column 'Income Verification Type' in Power BI:

```
Income Verification Type =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    HoldCode[HoldCode] <> "SELFCM", "Fully Verified",
    HoldCode[HoldCode] = "SELFCM", "Self Certified"
)
```

Got the below result as expected -

```
Income Verification Type
Fully Verified
Self Certified
```

But I want the result as below. I want to include or append the new value (Fast-track) to the above column.

```
Income Verification Type
Fully Verified
Self Certified
Fast-Track
```

There must be some DAX functions which should helps me to append the custom value to existing column.

Comment: Could you please post an example of your data? Also, it'd be helpful if you show how this data (full record, not just one column) should look like after the "append".

Comment: Below is the output (Income Verification Type) of above switch statement:

Income Verification Type Count of Number %GT %GT Count of Number Amount(GBP) %GT %GT Amount(GBP)
Fully Verified 126756 100.00% 9938385838 100.00%
Self Certified 1          0.00% 80948.84          0.00%

I want to include another row like below.

Income Verification Type Count of Number %GT %GT Count of Number Amount(GBP) %GT %GT Amount(GBP)
Fully Verified 126756 100.00% 9938385838 100.00%
Self Certified 1 0.00% 80948.84 0.00%
Fast-track 0 0.00% 0 0.00%

Comment: Sorry, I'm unable to share the result in tabular format.